# MySQL Update Queries

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have an sql file with 90000 update queries

```
UPDATE xxxx SET price='x.xx', wholesale_price='y.yy' WHERE reference='azerty';
```

I try to update my database with :

```
mysql -u user -ppassword ecommerce < update_prices-1360224708.sql
```

But after 2 hours and half... my update is not finished... and with my bad luck, my internet cut during my SSH session and i'm sure the update fails.

So... I decide to cut my fail on 10 files (10000 lines per file, weight = 1MO) ... but with phpmyadmin, too many requests...

How long does it take to 90,000 requests?

Do I fail something ? When I use "one line"... it works, i'm sure there is no error on the file.

Someone has an idea ?

Comment: Is `reference` column indexed?

Comment: In *theory* it shouldn't take that long with an index on `reference` (or a small-ish `xxxx` table), do you 1)have someone else connected to the database that may have a lock, or 2)have a trigger that takes forever on each update?

Comment: I haven't index on the column reference. Should I have an index and How can I set one ?

Comment: 90,000 update in 2 hrs it's like 12.5 updates/sec... that's TOO SLOW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create an index on reference:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_reference ON tablename (reference);
```

Comment: Yes, it was the solution. I haven't an index on my reference column. After add this index... the 90,000 queries work on less than 10 minutes... Yes =)